# animate number repeats when using appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate, viewport

I am using jquery animateNumber ( http://aishek.github.io/jquery-animateNumber/ ) to animate two numbers. This works as intended.

I am also using jquery appear ( http://morr.github.io/appear.html )

When I reload the site on the section where there numbers are placed, the animation works perfectly, but when I use it together with appear, it keeps repeating 4-5 times before stopping at the number it is supposed to.

I have no clue why is does this.

I have made a small recording of the issue.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7hawEXeq3fwWmdZdU1qbUwxOGs/view?usp=sharing

This is my script to control the animation

```
 $('#financialNumbers').appear();

        $('#financialNumbers').on('appear', function () {

            $('.timer.result').animateNumber(
              {
                  number: 690,
              }, 1500
            );

            var decimal_places = 1;
            var decimal_factor = decimal_places === 0 ? 1 : Math.pow(10, decimal_places);

            $('.timer.percentage').animateNumber(
             {
                 number: 11.9 * decimal_factor,
                 numberStep: function (now, tween) {
                     var floored_number = Math.floor(now) / decimal_factor,
                         target = $(tween.elem);

                     if (decimal_places > 0) {
                         // force decimal places even if they are 0
                         floored_number = floored_number.toFixed(decimal_places);

                         // replace '.' separator with ','
                         floored_number = floored_number.toString().replace('.', ',');
                     }

                     target.text(floored_number);
                 }
             }, 1500
           );

        });

        $('#financialNumbers').on('disappear', function () {
            $('.timer').text(0);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using jquery isinviewport